# text in PNG files is blurry in IE9+

Tags: png, adobe-fireworks

I've created some navigation images for use on a website and they appear blurry only in IE9 browser and above.  The font is arial and the size is 100 x 14 with 12 pt font. I've tried making the image 200 x 24 pixels and resizing on the web to 100 x 14 to no avail. I've tried using crisp and no anti-alias but still blurry.  [image: I've added a screen shot here]

Comment: You clearly have some incorrect size. Place them as backgrounds to block elements and they would be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I have to use images so alt tags can be used for SEO purposes. Unfortunately, I can't use html / css text or background images.

Comment: There is no need to use IMG tag for this. If this is an A tag you can hide the text by enclosing it in a SPAN with display: none; OR use text-indent with a very negative value of -100px if that's what you need to hide or just go -5000px.
This is the SEO approach because you will have the text present. Code: <a><span>SEO visible text

Answer (score 2):

For web, it is much better to design text elements using HTML and CSS than using images. The possibilities in modern standards are so good that the benefits with using images are much less now than they were before.